# How can i use assertion in Saml Request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, saml

I have implemented a Service Provider (SP) with Spring Boot and would like to generate a saml request like this:

```
<saml:Assertion Version="2.0" ID="_e2294424-9055-4b32-ac27-39c1c53f66e7" IssueInstant="2023-08-03T09:09:30.036Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <samlp:AuthnRequest Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-08-03T09:09:30.036Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL=..... xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" />
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                      Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
                      >.....
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">..</ds:Signature>
</saml:Assertion>
```

how can i configure spring security to obtain this saml request?

I currently get the following request, but I cannot insert the Assertion tag:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-08-03T09:09:30.036Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL=..... xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" />
     <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
              Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
             >......
     </saml2:Issuer>
     <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">..</ds:Signature>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to implement SP intiated SSO flow which include request and response. It seems like you understood something wrong because `Assertion` element can't be part of `AuthnRequest` element.
Minimal working example of `AuthnRequest` looks like this

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ONELOGIN_809707f0030a5d00620c9d9df97f627afe9dcc24" Version="2.0" ProviderName="SP test" IssueInstant="2014-07-16T23:52:45Z" Destination="http://idp.example.com/SSOService.php" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs">
  <saml:Issuer>http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" AllowCreate="true"/>
  <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
  </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

`Assertion` element is actually part of `Response` element that you're going to receive from identity provider. Example of response looks something like this

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_8e8dc5f69a98cc4c1ff3427e5ce34606fd672f91e6" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z" Destination="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685">
  <saml:Issuer>http://idp.example.com/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
  </samlp:Status>
  <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="_d71a3a8e9fcc45c9e9d248ef7049393fc8f04e5f75" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z">
    <saml:Issuer>http://idp.example.com/metadata.php</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID SPNameQualifier="http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">_ce3d2948b4cf20146dee0a0b3dd6f69b6cf86f62d7</saml:NameID>
      <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-01-18T06:21:48Z" Recipient="http://sp.example.com/demo1/index.php?acs" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_4fee3b046395c4e751011e97f8900b5273d56685"/>
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
    </saml:Subject>
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-07-17T01:01:18Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-01-18T06:21:48Z">
      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>http://sp.example.com/demo1/metadata.php</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
    <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-07-17T01:01:48Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2024-07-17T09:01:48Z" SessionIndex="_be9967abd904ddcae3c0eb4189adbe3f71e327cf93">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
    <saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:Attribute Name="uid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test@example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
      <saml:Attribute Name="eduPersonAffiliation" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">users</saml:AttributeValue>
        <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">examplerole1</saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
  </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Notice `Assertion` element here, it contains all the important data. Users `NameID` depending on the identity provider configuration, conditions under which this response is issued and SAML attributes.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hi @Filip, I agree with you but in SAML doc https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf,  paragraph 5.3 I found: "**A SAML assertion may be embedded within** another SAML element, such as an enclosing <Assertion> or a **request** or response, which may be signed". What dou you think about this sentence? It seems misleading to me...

Comment: I do agree that this part of documentation sounds misleading, but maybe the writer wanted to say something else.